# If JavaScript Served From Site-A, Issues a POST to Site-B, Will this Cause a CORS Violation?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make certain I understand SOP/CORS policy.  The particular scenario I'm interested in is:

An HMTL page and JavaScript are served from domain company-one.com.  However, the JavaScript code will issue a POST to domain company-two.com.

First assumption: I think the POST will fail due to origin policy. Is this correct?

Second assumption: If I setup an access control header (Acccess-Control-Allow-Origin: company-one.com) on the company-two.com server, the POST will work. Is this correct?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The POST will fail, but keep in mind JavaScript fetch/AJAX is not the only way to make POST requests. Even without an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, company-one.com can still make (and automatically submit) a form that would cause a POST request to company-two.com, possibly with the user's cookie.
2. Yes. Also consider adding [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods)

Comment: Excellent response.  Thank you.